# Notification not received sometimes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using Firebase Notifications on my project. The problem is when I'm sending the notification through my HP, the notification is sometimes not received.

Can somebody explain to me why does this happen?

Comment: You're going to need to give more info than that.. And also check your device isn't in power saving mode... It restricts background data usage.

Comment: more information are required to answer you:
how are you sending the message? which options are you setting? are you targeting ios or android?